# DRYing two very similar SQL conditional inserts

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two very similar SQL statements

```
INSERT INTO user_profile (user_id, setting_id, value)
    SELECT id, 18, true
    FROM users
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT user_id, setting_id FROM user_profile
            WHERE id=user_id AND setting_id=18);

INSERT INTO user_profile (user_id, setting_id, value)
    SELECT id, 16, true
    FROM users
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT user_id, setting_id FROM user_profile
            WHERE id=user_id AND setting_id=16);
```

I'm repeating everything except for the setting_id. Is there a way to combine these two statements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to create a stored procedure that takes your setting ID

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION InsertUserProfile(id INTEGER) 
RETURNS void AS $$
 BEGIN
   INSERT  INTO user_profile
     ( user_id ,
       setting_id ,
       value
     )
     SELECT  id ,
       id ,
       true
     FROM    users
     WHERE   NOT EXISTS ( SELECT user_id ,
            setting_id
           FROM   user_profile
           WHERE  id = id
            AND setting_id = @ID );
 END;
 $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

You'll then want to call it like this:

```
SELECT usp_InsertUserProfile(16)
```

Comment: The author of the post indicated the database is PostgreSQL, rather than TSQL, as such the above syntax in your answer would not work. Perhaps you can edit it to fit PostgreSQL syntax.

Comment: I've amended the solution for postgres

Comment: The code does not look correct after the edit. You now have two `id` (one is a function parameter and the other a table column, before it was `@id` and `id` ).